# Connecting to ec2-instance using a non-ssh connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I'am working at a place where the firewall blocks connection to external servers.and i want to get connected to my amazon-ec2 instance from my work-place...i have already tried using VPN to connect but it didn't work.Does any kind of port-forwarding techniques work.Any solution would be fine.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your `sshd_config` setting to open ssh on multiple port - Just make sure to edit your security group of your instance to open the port you set from the setting.

Comment: Thanks for writing back... can we use port 443 for this? i hope my office allows traffic only on port 80 and 443 ....

Comment: you'd need at least to connect once to change the file `ssh_config` which controls which ssh port are opened to connect so you could had port that are opened from your corporate firewall. Then this same port must also be added in your inbound security group rule to allow this port to be opened on your ec2 instance

Comment: yes you could use 443 - make sure there's nothing else running on port 443 on your instance. you need to add the 443 port for the ec2 host in your local `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: U mean in the ssh_config file in the ec2 instance right?

Comment: Yes you'd need to make the change on the ec2